# How to read the statement print_r($answer_keyword_arr->$language[0]) in php

Tags: arrays

Why can't `php` read this one?

```
print_r($answer_keyword_arr->$language[0])
```

but this one it can read:

```
print_r($answer_keyword_arr->lang_1[0])
$language = 'lang_1'
```

Comment: Did you call `$language = 'lang_1'` **before** or **after** `print_r`?

Comment: No. Im not call $language

Comment: if i write like this $answer_keyword_arr->lang_1[0] is okey.. But i want define 'lang_1' is variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap with `{}` like below:

```
print_r($answer_keyword_arr->{$language}[0]);
```